# Prove that $\mathcal T_2$ is a topology on $\mathbb N$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathbb N$ be the set of all positive integers and $\mathcal T_2$ consist of $\mathbb N$, $\emptyset$ and every set $\{ n, n+1, \dots \}$ for any positive integer $n$.
>
> Prove that $\mathcal T_2$ is a topology on $\mathbb N$.

Clearly $\mathbb N$ and $\emptyset \in \mathcal T_2$.

Let $A_i, A_j \in \mathcal T_2$ and define $A = A_i \cap A_j$. We must show that $A \in \mathcal T_2$. If $A_i = A_j$, then clearly $A \in \mathcal T_2$. If $A_i \neq A_j$, but $A_i \subset A_j$, then $A = A_i \in \mathcal T_2$. Similarly, if $A_j \subset A_i$, then $A = A_j \in \mathcal T_2$. Also note that for any $A_i \in \mathcal T_2$, we have $A_i \cap \mathbb N = A_i \in \mathcal T_2$ and $A_i \cap \emptyset = \emptyset \in \mathcal T_2$.

I now still need to show that $\mathcal T_2$ is closed under (finite or infinite) union. I am not sure how to do this in this example?

Comment: These subsets form a chain, and every chain containing $\emptyset$ and the whole set form a topology.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the open sets of your topology are essentially all intervals of the form $[n,+\infty)$ (in the natural numbers, with $n\in\mathbb{N}$), together with the empty set.

Note also that $$\bigcup_{i\in I}[n_i,+\infty)=[\min\{n_i:i\in I\},+\infty)$$ and $$\bigcap_{i=1}^k [n_i,+\infty)=[\max\{n_1,\ldots,n_k\},+\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Denote by $A_n: = \{k \in \mathbb{N}\ |\ k \geq n\}$. Then, $A_n \cap A_m = A_{\mathrm{max} \{m,n\}}$. If $(n_i)_{i \in I}$ is a family of natural numbers, then, if $I = \emptyset$, we have $\bigcup_I A_{n_i} = \emptyset$. If $I \not= \emptyset$, then there is a minimum $n$ of all the $n_i$. Then $\bigcup_I A_{n_i}=A_n$.